# root change (SCREEN OFF )

Tags: permissions, linux-mint

I have changed some permissions in my local filesystem in Linux Mint 19 c'mm. after changing the access level from root to user and changing the effect in my folder(subfolders basically), I am now not able to login into my system.

I can only see the Linux Mint screen, which is continuously loading without any effect on my system. It seems like it has crashed. How can I get back into my account to save my data?

Comment: I think that you may have to let us know a bit more about what specific changes you made to your system.

Comment: so here is what happened:
I was trying to create a folder in my file storage folder, but due to root level permissions I couldn't directly create the folder. So i gave root access and did create the folder, but i wanted the permissions to be available for my local host as well. So after giving the permissions to my local host, i saved the changes, then my screen just went off and then i forced shut down the system. now when i am switching on the system, it just goes to boot loader and tries to load mint but nothing is happening.

Comment: <i tried with system recovery mode as well, but to no avail. I went to login with root credentials in recovery mode and can see my files but after that i don't know what next shall I do. The GUI is simply just not loading. I want to come back to GUI without setting up the whole system from fresh new installation of mint.

Comment: It's still unclear what you actually did. How did you change the permissions (the exact commands) and what did you change permission on?

Comment: I am so sad that I can't actually show the screen of what happened. But maybe this helps:
I wanted to copy my data from an external drive to my computer hard disk. I tried to create folder where my file storage is there(it is also where I installed my linux..e.g c:\ on windows). I didn't create any partition. so everything of my data is on the same disk space. So basically i saw that in order to perform any operations i needed to authenticate as root, which was perfectly fine but then i wanted to authenticate it also as local guest, that as guest i can create folder and do operations.

Comment: so I saw on internet that i can first authenticate as root user and then change the credentials to my host name. so i selected my host name from permissions tab and changed the setting to read/write and in the group box under permission tab, i changed the permissions to root and read/write and then checked for subfolders options, then applied the changes. as soon as i did it, the icons on my desktop went off and then suddenly all went black on screen. It was written, the changes will take place after restart. so i restarted my system and since then my GUI is not loading. onlyBootScreenIsThere

Comment: Can you login in recovery mode, and run the command `ls -ld / /bin /lib` ? Does it show the owner is `root`, or somebody else?